# How to write factory_girl create command using fabrication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot, fabrication-gem

I am learning how to use [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#getting-started) in `Rails` and we have decided to replace all our `factory_girl` code with fabrication.

Suppose we have this code in `factory_girl`, how will I rewrite the whole thing using `fabrication`?

```
FactoryGirl.create(
  :payment,
  user: user_ny,
  amount: -4000,
  booking: booking,
  payable: payable]
)
```

Is this the correct code using Fabrication ? I am new to rails framework and will appreciate your help.

```
Fabricator(:payment) do
  name { user_ny }
  amount -4000
  booking { booking }
  payable { payable }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabrication's equivalent to `FactoryGirl.create(:payment)` is `Fabricate(:payment)`.

It looks like `booking` and `payable` are other fabricators so you could write it like this:

```
Fabricate(:payment, name: user_ny) do
  amount -4000
  booking
  payable
end
```

If you declare a relationship without a "value" it performs a default expansion and generates whatever the fabricator of the same name defines and sets it on the object.

In the case of `user_ny` above, the easiest way to use a local variable when fabricating is to pass it in as a parameter. You can mix and match however you want between the parameters and block syntax, although parameters will take precedence.